# CollectionTypes and event listener Symfony 2.8

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a list of fields that each can be of type "select" or "radio" buttons.

so I have a collectionType ProductOptions, and each element of the collection is a OptionGroup with one entityType on the result is

- optionGroup.name : select( optionElements )
- optionGroup.name : radio( optionElements )
  ...

the optionElements of one OptionGroup (entityType) are set with an POST_SET_DATA.

what I want to do now is, when the first entityType is changed the second one is filed with optionElements (with ajax) and so on...

if we have filled 5 entityTypes and we change the first one, the 4 next will be removed (with for example an hide in jquery)

How it is possible to do so ?
Thank you in advance.

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
    ->add('productOptionGroups', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => ProductOptionGroupType::class,
        'label' => false,
        'required' => true,
    ));
}
```

and option groups

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function ($event) {
        $builder = $event->getForm();
        $entity = $event->getData();
        $optionGroup = $entity->getOptionGroup();
        $optionType = $optionGroup->getOptionType();
        $elements = $entity->getOptionElements(); // or a query builder

        if($optionType == OptionGroup::OPTIONGROUP_TYPE_SELECT){
        $builder
        ->add('elements', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AnaShopBundle:OptionElement',
            'choices' => $elements,
            'label' => $optionGroup,
            'required' => true,
            'property' => 'name',
            'mapped' => false,

        ));
        } elseif ($optionType == OptionGroup::OPTIONGROUP_TYPE_RADIO) {
            $builder
            ->add('elements', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AnaShopBundle:OptionElement',
                'choices' => $elements,
                'label' => $optionGroup,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'property' => 'name',
                'mapped' => false,
            ));
        } 

    });
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your question adding your client side code attempt (ajax and so on).

Comment: I don't have the ajax of the client side yet, as I don't know how to solve this problem.